# How to store the several time periods into MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a column which stores time periods such as

```
|tcolumn                                                                   |
|1990-01-01 ~ 1990-02-05, 1995-05-02 ~ 1995-08-01                          |
|1992-03-01 ~ 1996-05-02, 1997-07-02 ~ 1998-11-01, 2001-03-02 ~ 2002-08-01 |
|1997-08-01 ~ 1998-07-12                                                   |
```

Each row can store a different number of time periods.

And I want to index the column to check if the specific time periods' set is in the column.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

I have some ideas but all gets quite complicated.

(I use python to access the database.)

Comment: Normalize your table. One period per row, start and finish in separate columns.

Comment: @Akina In the case, I don't know how to index it.

Comment: Index creation cannot be self-goal, index creation without definite goals list makes no sense. It is created for something - primary key identifies rows, unique keys provides uniqueness (and foreign key support on the side "one"), keys provides queries speed increase and foreign key support on the side "many"...

Comment: @Akina The reason I want to index is to check if there is a specific time period set. I want to do queries such as finding all the rows which have a specific time period set.

Comment: *check if there is a specific time period set* Define this term. Does "set" means that its start and finish are strictly equal to searching criteria? or overlapped? or covered? or equal with some accuracy? Or something else?

Comment: @Akina For example, this is one set, (1990-01-01 ~ 1990-02-05, 1995-05-02 ~ 1995-08-01). The start and end of each period should be equal strictly.

Comment: Do you have some single datetime value, and you must find the periods sets which this datetime is included into?

Comment: No, I don't need the query. I only need to check if all the start and end are equal exactly.

Comment: If so look for solution provided by **Strawberry** - it solves. Additionally this solution may provide ordering check (in your structure `(1990-01-01 ~ 1990-02-05, 1995-05-02 ~ 1995-08-01)` and `(1995-05-02 ~ 1995-08-01, 1990-01-01 ~ 1990-02-05)` are not identical). *I only need to check if all the start and end are equal exactly.* I am very interested in how do you want to check **without a query**...

Comment: I need a query of course. I meant to say that I don't need the query checking a single datetime value.

Comment: Nevertheless the query which uses normalized structure will be more effective than searching in CSV which cannot be indexed effectively. Of course you may suppost strict ordering of subperiods on the client level for both data and criteria - in such case single indexing for source table by periods set column will help, but this method is unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a normalised environment

```
t_id start_date end_date
   1 1990-01-01 1990-02-05
   1 1995-05-02 1995-08-01
   2 1992-03-01 1990-05-02
   2 1997-07-02 1998-11-01
   2 2001-03-02 2002-08-01
   3 1997-08-01 1998-07-12
```

In this example, it's assumed that a PRIMARY KEY can be formed on (t_id,start_date)